# Delete record based on condition from mongo database using jmeter

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I am trying to delete the record from Mongo database using jmeter jsr223 groovy protocol but getting error.

Request:
     --delete the records which is retrieved between the insert date 
MongoCollection Collection = database.getCollection("TEST_COMM");
    Collection`enter code here`.deleteMany{
    $and: [
        {
            "insertDate": {
                $gte: ISODate("2019-10-15T15:16:45.328+0000") 
            }
        }
        ,
        {
            "insertDate": {
                $lte: ISODate("2019-10-15T17:02:44.017+0000") 
            }
        }
    ]
}
Response:
  Script1.groovy: 50: expecting '}', found ':' @ line 50, column 25.
                                   "insertDate": {
                                               ^

Can someone help in resolving the issue.

Comment: Not sure about jmeter specifically, but you may want to enclose parameters in parenthesis.  Example:  .deleteMany({ $and: [ { "insertDate": { $gte: ISODate("2019-10-15T15:16:45.328+0000") } } , { "insertDate": { $lte: ISODate("2019-10-15T17:02:44.017+0000") } } ] })

Comment: Thanks Barry! but JMeter is not recognizing the string when i passed.

Comment: Hi @Lee.  Can you please post the error message?

Comment: i am not getting any error at jmeter tool but the records are not deleted from database.

Comment: I believe JMeter is Java, right?  Your example request code looks like Mongo Query Language, not Java.  Do you have any working JMeter Groovy code that can interoperate with MongoDB?  If so, would you mind sharing?